# Autofac Resolve<IEnumerable<T>>() returns empty list

Tags: c#, .net, autofac

I have read lots of Autofac docs/wikis which indicate I can get a list of all the registered types by doing something as simple as shown below:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
                .AssignableTo<IPersistedModel>();
var container = builder.Build();
var allTypes = container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IPersistedModel>>();
```

The problem is allTypes comes up empty.

In the debugger I can see inside the container and there are 7 matching types and even an array of IPersistedModel... but they do not get returned on Resolve().

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to register the types as the interface, either using `.As<IPersistedModel>()` or for all its interfaces using `.AsImplementedInterfaces()`:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
            .AssignableTo<IPersistedModel>()
            .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

Comment: i believe this works without `AssignableTo<IPersistedModel>()` atleast in 3.5

Comment: @arviman Yes, it would. That's just to restrict which types are registered (without it, it will register _all_ types in the assembly, which is probably not what you want).